# how can i write gherkin language test cases in robot framework

Tags: robotframework, bdd

i want to write test cases as we right in cucumber.
Like we have feature file where we store given when then and we make step definition file we write code.
How can i achieve that BDD style in robot. without using selenium library. i want to do api testing using it.

libraries and sample code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Robot Framework has a 'RobotDemo' repository on GitHub, providing example .robot files that use gherkin syntax (given, when, then).

Here's a snippet from the given example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Addition
    Given calculator has been cleared
    When user types "1 + 1"
    and user pushes equals
    Then result is "2"

*** Keywords ***
Calculator has been cleared
    Push button    C

User types "${expression}"
    Push buttons    ${expression}

User pushes equals
    Push button    =

Result is "${result}"
    Result should be    ${result}
```

See the full example: https://github.com/robotframework/RobotDemo/blob/master/gherkin.robot

The Robot Framework User Guide also provides instruction on how to write test cases in a behaviour driven style:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Valid Login
    Given login page is open
    When valid username and password are inserted
    and credentials are submitted
    Then welcome page should be open
```

See the documentation: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#behavior-driven-style

Comment: yes went through this but specifically if i say, i am not sure about any keywords or how to test APIs and also do assertions in it. so looking for it.